# Getting working time details of ms project schedule saved as ms-access mdb file?

Tags: c#, ms-access, calendar, ms-project

I'm working on a work progress application which is based on an Microsoft Project schedule. I'm saving this schedule as mdb (Microsoft Access) file and access it with an C# application.
The problem now is, that in the project table (MSP_PROJECT) only saves the used calendar by its name (PROJ_INFO_CAL_NAME) which might not be unique. To get the exact calendar data for my calculations I need the CAL_UID which I can't find.

Is there any other way to get the calendar uid to read the default working times and the exceptions in this mdb export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a project, the calendar names are unique: MS Project won't allow you to create duplicates. You could use the following query to retrieve the calendar you are interested in:

```
select * from MSP_CALENDARS where PROJ_ID=? and CAL_NAME=?
```